# How to reset index in python after aggregating dataframe results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a dataframe with lots of rows and columns on score results. I want to aggregate them and look at how many records there are with each score. Ideally the output would look like:

df=

```
Score    count
10       576
9        306
8        644
7        829
etc...
```

I've been using the below code to try to get the main dataframe into that format.

```
df = df[['score']]
df = df.groupby(['score'])['score'].count()
df = df.reset_index()
```

This code works for the most part, the second line gets me the aggregated figures for each score, but the scores themselves are in the index as opposed to being their own column which is why I try to reset the index.

However I keep getting the error: ValueError: cannot insert score, already exists.

Anyway to get around this so I can have the two columns; score and count.

Comment: Could you edit your post with your original dataframe so we can replicate it?

Comment: `df['Score'].value_counts().reset_index(name='Count')`.

Answer (score 0):

**Sol 1**

```
df = df.groupby(['score']).count()
df = df.reset_index()

df
   score    count
0   7   1
1   8   1
2   9   1
3   10  1
```

**Sol 2**

```
df = df[['score']]
df = df.groupby(['score']).size()
df = df.reset_index()

df
    score   0
0   7       1
1   8       1
2   9       1
3   10      1
```